# how to find approximate words in python using find

Tags: python

I need to find the first character of a word in many sentences. All of the sentences have some form of the word 'conjecture', i.e. conjectures, conjectured, etc. However I can't use wildcards inside 'find' like this

```
firstSpace = mySentence.find('conjecture'*,0)
```

the sentences look like:

```
'There is considerable conjecture and debate as to how...'
'He conjectured that the interface was...'
```

Any ideas how can I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Do any of them not start with "conjecture"? If not, why not just use `mySentence.find("conjecture")`?

Comment: Some start with capital C = Conjecture.... for that it doesn't work...

Comment: Ok, so what about `mySentence.lower().find("conjecture")`

Comment: That did the trick, with the capitals thanks!, however some words start with the nasty characters: â€œ or the like.. how can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try removing the special characters first:

```
x = 'â€œ There is considerable conjecture and debate as to how...

newx = ''.join(e for e in x.lower() if e.isalnum())

print newx

>>> 'thereisconsiderableconjectureanddebateastohow'
```

Then use `find` to locate your word.

Good luck!

EDIT:

If you want to find words that precede your specified word, you could split up your sentences. Here is a piece of code that might be of help:

```
paragraph = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. I have two big dogs. Furry Dogs are the best. $%^Dogs love me.'
paragraph = ''.join(e for e in paragraph.lower() if e.isalnum() or e.isspace() or e=='.')
sentence_list = paragraph.split('.')
prev_word_list = []
for sentence in sentence_list:
    word_list = sentence.split()
    prev_word = ''
    for i,word in enumerate(word_list):
        if i == 0:
            pass
        else:
            if 'dog' in word.lower():
                prev_word = word_list[i-1]
                prev_word_list.append(prev_word)
```

This gives:

```
>>> print prev_word_list
>>> ['lazy', 'big', 'furry']
```

Comment: newx = ''.join(e for e in x.lower() if e.isalnum() or e.isspace()) will give 'there is considerable conjecture and debate as to how'

Comment: Putting aside Unicode issues `paragraph.split('.')` could fail on ~5% of sentences depending on text. It might be acceptable in some cases. Otherwise `nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize` might provide better results. Why do you use `.split(' ')` instead of `.split()`? `word_list[i-1]` fails (silently) on the first word in a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

> All of the sentences have some form of the word 'conjecture', i.e. conjectures, conjectured, etc.

`word in string` methods shown in other answers will fail in general e.g., they won't find the word `community` in a sentence that has `communities` in it.

In this case you might need a stemming algorithm such as provided by [`nltk.stem` package](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.stem-module.html):

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import EnglishStemmer
from nltk import word_tokenize

stemmer = EnglishStemmer()
stem_word = stemmer.stem

stem = stem_word(u"conjecture")
sentence = u'He conjectured that the interface was...'
words = word_tokenize(sentence)
found_words = [(i, w) for i, w in enumerate(words) if stem_word(w) == stem]
# -> [(1, u'conjectured')]
```

There are other stem and [tokenize methods in nltk](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) that you could use depending on what you need exactly.

> however some words start with the nasty characters: â€œ or the like.. how can I get rid of them?

"nasty characters" is the result of incorrectly treating `utf-8` byte sequences as `cp1252`:

```
>>> utf8bytes = u"microsoft smart quote (\u201c)".encode('utf-8')
>>> print utf8bytes.decode('cp1252')
microsoft smart quote (â€œ)
>>> print utf8bytes.decode('utf-8')
microsoft smart quote (“)
```

You shouldn't blindly remove garbled text, fix the character encoding instead.

[Why the #AskObama Tweet was Garbled on Screen: Know your UTF-8, Unicode, ASCII and ANSI Decoding Mr. President](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhyTheAskObamaTweetWasGarbledOnScreenKnowYourUTF8UnicodeASCIIAndANSIDecodingMrPresident.aspx) shows a publicized on television example of this issue.

To understand read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 1):

Forgetting the implicit work that is actually being done in the background, this will at least achieve the task you're asking for (hopefully).

```
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', mySentence).encode('ascii', 'ignore').lower().find("conjecture")
```

Well I'm going to be honest, I expected a regex to set you up for a linear search, but the unicode values often split into two "characters".

Instead, here's a hack that at least gets the job done:

```
newSentence = ""
for i in range(0, len(mySentence)):
   if ord(mySentence[i]) > 128:
         newSentence += '_'
   else:
         newSentence += mySentence[i]

newSentence.encode("UTF-8").lower().find("conjecture")
```

If you want to just forget about those pesky encoded characters:

```
mySentence.decode("ascii", "ignore").encode("UTF-8").lower().find("conjecture")



Sample input: >>> newStr = "â€œ32f fWF  3(*&(%FJ   conJectuRe€@!O".decode("ascii", "ignore").encode("UTF-8").lower()
              >>> print newStr
              >>> print newStr.find("conjecture")

Output:       '32f fwf  3(*&(%fj   conjecture@!o'
              20
```

Comment: And at this point you'd have to convert it to unicode. So...are you sure you want to use `find` instead of `re`?

Comment: how can I use the re module??

Comment: Sorry I've been having difficulties with my interpreter...gimme a sec

Comment: @OliverAmundsen hi just `import re` in your python code and full document here : http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: thanks, but I'm finding it hard to replace the weird characters, even the '.'

Comment: Wow, you've got all sorts of stuff in that sentence. Would it be against your intention to remove those characters?

Comment: I need to clean the sentence up so that I can identify the word that precedes conjecture...

Comment: Then forget about the rest of my code and just use the last line. Maybe even split it up a bit.